# (x86) Is the value of ESP relative to EBP, or not?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, stack-frame, stack-pointer

I always used to think that `SP` was relative to `BP`, meaning that pushing and popping stuff on the stack would use the address `BP` - `SP`, with `BP` being the start of the stack, and `SP` being the current item on the top of the stack. However, after looking at the CDECL calling convention, that would not make sense, as `SP` is assigned to the value of `BP`. So, if I change `BP`, does that even affect `SP`? Is `BP` even used for `push`/`pop` instructions? Or does `push`/`pop` just work with `SP`? Is `BP` even needed?

Comment: BP is the base pointer used within a function to identify the beginning of the activation frame - the actual parameters passed into the function. The Stack pointer is then free to change within the function (and any that it calls). It means the compiler does not need to consider any further stack changes within the function.

Comment: On the original 8088 | 8086, there were no instructions that could use `sp`  for memory access so `bp` was used instead.  Using `bp` for memory assess defaulted to `ss`, `bx` and `si` defaulted to `ds` and `di` defaulted to `es`.  `ax`, `cx`, and `dx` could not be used for memory access either.

Comment: Look at the manual for the instructions you're interested in; their pseudocode shows they only read and modify SP (or ESP or RSP depending on the stack address size attribute of SS). https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, if I change BP, does that even effect SP? Is BP even used for push/pop instructions?

No, and no.

`BP`/`EBP`/`RBP` is often used to hold the address of the current [stack frame](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames) of a function. That is, an address relative to the function's arguments and local variables that will stay the same throughout the function (whereas the stack pointer might change temporarily).
Instructions like `PUSH` / `POP` or `CALL` / `RET` will change `SP`/`ESP`/`RSP` but not `BP`/`EBP`/`RBP`.

Answer (score 3):

None of the general registers in x86 have "spurious action at a distance", changing one does not touch any of the others. BP is just an ordinary register. It's used by convention to store the base of the current stack frame, but that's it (and that's not even done some most of the time when optimizing, because it is rarely necessary). SP is also an ordinary register, but it is special in the sense that it is modified implicitly by certain instructions, namely `push`, `pop`, `call`, `ret`, etc., and it must maintain proper stack discipline or function calls (or rather, *returns*) will break.